# How to join 2 text files using bash scripting?

Tags: bash

I want to combine 2 files and and put together in 1 file [only 2 fields (`$4` and `$5` in `FILE A`, `$2` and `$3` in `FILE B`) are the common thing between the two files]. See below desired output.

## FILE A:

```
X 2134 101L 12345.00 22222.00  1 10

X 2134 101L 12345.00 22222.00 11 20 

X 2134 101L 12345.00 22222.00 21 30 

X 2134 111L 77777.00 22222.00  1 10 

X 2134 111L 77777.00 22222.00 11 20 

X 2134 111L 77777.00 22222.00 21 30 

X 2134 121L 56347.00 46678.00  1 10 

X 2134 121L 56347.00 46678.00 11 20 

X 2134 121L 56347.00 46678.00 21 3
```

## FILE B:

```
3333 12345 22222 54367.05 34765.05

3333 34567 12235 54298.05 34568.05 

3333 77777 22222 52765.05 32567.05 

3333 55555 11111 52875.05 36547.05 

3333 56347 46678 53789.05 34566.05
```

## RESULT:

```
3333 2134 10 12345 22222 54367.05 34765.05 

3333 NA   NA 34567 12235 54298.05 34568.05 

3333 2134 11 77777 22222 52765.05 32567.05 

3333 NA   NA 55555 11111 52875.05 36547.05 

3333 2134 12 56347 46678 53789.05 34566.05
```

HI guys,
I add one picture and I hope it will describe well my requirement. Thanks
[the desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBIOx.png)

Comment: @Cyrus I would appreciate if you could be more specific with your criticism. I usually use preformatted text for code and blockquotes for anything else. I suppose in that case preformatted text is more appropriate.

Comment: I suggest to remove empty lines and prefix lines with four whitespaces.

Comment: how did this match `3333 NA NA 55555 11111 52875.05 36547.05` ?  It's not in file1.

Comment: I think your field counting is off.  Can you write an example with which field values matched?

Comment: @Cyrus I cannot know whether the empty lines are actually part of the files / expected output or not.

Comment: Oops, you forgot to post your code! StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code and improve their understanding of programming. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Meta-code, even, will demonstrate how you're thinking a program should work, even if you don't know how to write it.

Answer (score 0):

Below script will work for above mentioned case.

```
while read line
do
value1=`echo $line |awk '{print $1}'`
value2=`echo $line |awk '{print $2}'`
value4=`echo $line |awk '{print substr($0, index($0,$3))}'`
value3=`grep $value2 fileA.txt|head -n 1|awk '{print $2" "$3}'|sed 's/1L//'`
if [ "$value3" == "" ];then
echo $value1" NA NA "$value4 >> result.txt
else
echo $value1" "$value3" "$value2" "$value4 >> result.txt
fi

done<fileB.txt
```

output:

```
3333 2134 10 12345 22222 54367.05 34765.05
3333 NA NA 12235 54298.05 34568.05
3333 2134 11 77777 22222 52765.05 32567.05
3333 NA NA 11111 52875.05 36547.05
3333 2134 12 56347 46678 53789.05 34566.05
```

PS:run this script using bash instead of sh.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{$4=$4+0;$5=$5+0; 
               if(!(($4,$5) in a)) a[$4,$5]=$2 FS $7;;next}
              {$2=((($2,$3) in a)?a[$2,$3]:"NA" FS "NA") FS $2}1' file{A,B}

3333 2134 10 12345 22222 54367.05 34765.05
3333 NA NA 34567 12235 54298.05 34568.05
3333 2134 10 77777 22222 52765.05 32567.05
3333 NA NA 55555 11111 52875.05 36547.05
3333 2134 10 56347 46678 53789.05 34566.05
```

you want to have the first match from fileA where there are multiple matches, the format of the fields don't match in both files (decimal point vs integers).

If you pipe to `... | column -t`

```
3333  2134  10  12345  22222  54367.05  34765.05
3333  NA    NA  34567  12235  54298.05  34568.05
3333  2134  10  77777  22222  52765.05  32567.05
3333  NA    NA  55555  11111  52875.05  36547.05
3333  2134  10  56347  46678  53789.05  34566.05
```

Comment: I think the OP was looking for a bash solution ... but even so, the question should be closed, as it doesn't include any code.